# Maven : Not able to download only specific plugin 2.0.6 in Eclipse Luna

Tags: eclipse, maven, maven-plugin, maven-compiler-plugin

I get the below error only for 2.0.6 plugin and none other, I tried all the links given in stack overflow for this, none worked for me.

```
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/2.0.6/maven-compiler-plugin-2.0.6.pom
[WARNING] The POM for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:jar:2.0.6 is missing, no dependency information available
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/2.0.6/maven-compiler-plugin-2.0.6.jar
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2.901 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-01-06T17:00:54+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 8M/148M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.0.6 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Could not find artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:jar:2.0.6
n central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2) -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginResolutionException
```

Comment: How did you come by this plugin version number? It doesn't seem to exist on Maven central: http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22org.apache.maven.plugins%22%20AND%20a%3A%22maven-compiler-plugin%22

Comment: What version of Maven are you using? It looks like you should consider migrating to a more recent Maven (try 3.3.9).